# MongoDB one server problems/pittfalls

Tags: mongodb, server, database-installation

I'm working on a project using MongoDB and therefor asked my server manager to install MongoDB.

I recently read on an old stackoverflow thread that it is not really recommended to run MongoDB on a single server, because of a possibility of data loss.
I'm not really an expert and want to avoid such cases.
Do these problems still exist and should I look for another solution like remote databases or is it safe to install it?

What are pitfalls that I should make sure my managed server provider takes care of?

Comment: This [article](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/mongodb-single-server-data-durability-guide/) may be of use.

Comment: Warning: the article describes the situation of version 1.5 from July 2010. Today, almost 4 and a half years later, we're at version 2.6.5. Much has changed since then, especially regarding single-server durability and default settings.

Comment: Put simply, you do want to have replica sets with at least two data bearing nodes and an arbiter for production. It is a relatively cheap way to basically eliminate the majority of downtime reasons from the database side: maintenance. I usually suggest to have at least 3 data bearing nodes to have redundancy even during maintenance work. In general, your question is a bit off topic on SO (which is aimed at _programming_ questions), so I kindly ask you to post it on http://dba.stackexchange.com and delete it here. I will happy to give a more detailed answer there.

Comment: I think this is borderline stackoverflow, because the behavior depends on what you do in your code - not setting the `j : true` flag makes this a different issue, and pure replication isn't an answer to durability to concerns, but as you point out, to availability. While I agree that replication is great and should be done whenever possible, I'd like to emphasize that a single-server MongoDB is no less durable than a single server MySQL or PostgreSQL, etc. I use single-server deployments a lot for small / hobby projects, where three servers are too expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning - the article linked to by chridam is *dangerously* out-of-date.

Simply put, *no*, there's not much to worry about with single server deployments of MongoDB anymore. By default, MongoDB will write everything to the journal every 100ms. If there are writes with the `j` (journal) option, that interval is shortened to a third. I have posted [a longer answer with the gritty details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488209/does-mongodb-journaling-guarantee-durability/18577429#18577429) (two, actually) to a similar question some time ago.

The point is that a write operation with `j : true` won't return until the write made it to the journal (i.e., expect these calls to take 16ms+, on average), and that's exactly the behavior one would expect and that's also how most other dbs behave.

You should ensure you're using the journalling write concern (`j : true`) and journalling isn't disabled. Also, since the defaults depend on the server version and there's lots of new features, bugfixes and performance improvements, make sure you're getting a somewhat recent version of MongoDB (might not be the case if the server runs something like debian stable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll upvote as soon as I got enough reputation. You answer was very helpful.