# Relational or NoSQL database for application

Tags: database, nosql, relational-database

I will be working on application which should manage instracompany documentation. It should work like this: User can upload a document with mandatory fields like: description, when document will be accessible for "readers", group of people who should approve the document, group of people who should read the document after successful approval... then history of documents, which decision each user made (aggred x disaggreed), some basic managment of users/groups/documents/roles etc... This application should be for a company (and it should run on local network).

- Should I use relational database with ORM or NoSQL database? And why? What would be benefits of relation db or nosql related to description of application above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strictly defined schema (seems to be the case) and predictable traffic (which is also very likely in a corporate environment) and want ACID transactions and data recovery guarantees which have been tested and polished for many years (you surely do) then RDBMS is your choice. It doesn't matter what is used on the application side, ORM, plain JDBC or whatever.

One slippery point might be the document storage, however, provided that documents are not huge, relational databases (e.g. PostgreSQL) will do the job just fine.

This assumes that you do not expect hundreds of thousands requests per second and thus don't need any sharding. Even if you do expect such load, RDBMS may be okay.

Comment: thanks for reply. 1) If I should explain to someone why I have chosen this type of db (relational) what would be the arguments? -strictly defined schema, predictable traffics, ACID (i dont think that I will actually need it in my application, but i am not sure...)... 2) how do you mean "data recovery"? This can be achieved only with RDBMS? you cannot recover your data with nosql db?

Comment: Data durability surely is not specific to RDBMS, however, its implementation in the popular databases in pretty mature, while NoSQL may suffer from childhood diseases (e.g. see this a bit outdated discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18488209/does-mongodb-journaling-guarantee-durability)

There are ACID transactions in Mongo DB 4+, however they have significant limitations: http://www.dbta.com/Columns/MongoDB-Matters/Limitations-in-MongoDB-Transactions-127057.aspx


You surely want ACID transactions e.g. if you don't like when doc approvers are written partially.

Comment: > what would be the arguments? ...predictable traffics

Traffic is not the property of storage, it is the property of application use. NoSQL database scales more easy than RDBMS, so if you expect huge traffic spikes, it makes sense to consider NoSQL. However, if your traffic is predictable then this advantage of NoSQL renders useless.

Comment: thanks for your all responses. Would you please explain me, how do you mean " You surely want ACID transactions e.g. if you don't like when doc approvers are written partially" ? What does it mean "written parially"?